# Regular, Context-free, Recursive, Recursively Enumerable Language Relationships

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar

I am currently under the believe that all regular languages are context free, thus all regular languages are recursive, and therefore all regular languages are recursively enumerable.

If I am given a question where one must select **exactly one** of these types of a languages for a given language L, then for each language the answer must be recursively enumerable? Am I correct in this assumption or am I missing something? Point me in the right direction if so.

Comment: Usually you’re expected to respond with the most restrictive classification that applies. Thus, if the language is regular, you should pick *regular*. If it’s context-free but not regular, you should pick *context-free*. And so on.

Comment: Ok that is probably what I am supposed to do, thanks.

Comment: You’re welcome.